# undefined refrence to 'memcpy' linking for elf_i386

Tags: c, gcc, linker, osdev

I am trying to link a c file for my custom kernel and I keep getting this error.
This is my c file:

```
#include <string.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void main() {
    char vmem_back_buffer[3932160];
    char** vmem_descriptor = (char**)0x00008128;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1280*1024*3; ++i) {
        vmem_back_buffer[i] = 0xfb;
        vmem_back_buffer[i++] = 0xfb;
        vmem_back_buffer[i++] = 0xfb;
    }

    memcpy(*vmem_descriptor, vmem_back_buffer, 3932160);

    while(TRUE) {
        int i = 1;
    }
}
```

And here is how I compile and link

```
gcc -m32 -fno-pie -ffreestanding  -c src/kernel.c -o bin/kernel.o
ld   -m elf_i386 -o bin/kernel.bin -T src/linker.l bin/kernel_entry.o bin/kernel.o --oformat binary
```

I have uninstalled and installed different c library packages, tried to include stuff like `crti.o` as many sources online recommend, among other things.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: none of the included libraries contain the definition of `memcpy`

Comment: You are writing a kernel and doing it freestanding. The C library isn't available. You will need to implement/provide your own `memcpy` .

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware you could not use other libraries. Made the mistake of copy-pasting those command options without understanding them